# Pattern Generation Recursion

Tags: recursion

I'm writing a program to generate all possible combination of a string 1*0* by replacing * by 0 or 1. This program only gives 3 values and is missing one value. Can someone help me find out the issue in this code?

For input 1*0*, this solution only gives 3 results: 1000, 1001, 1101. The missing value is 1100. Thanks.

```html
public class TestClass{
        public static void generateComb (char[] ch, int index) {
            if (index == ch.length)
            {
                System.out.println (ch);

                return;
            }
            if (ch[index]=='*'){

                ch[index] = '0';
                generateComb (ch, index+1);
                ch[index] = '1';

                generateComb (ch, index+1);                        
            }
            else {
                generateComb (ch, index+1);   
                
            }
        }
        
        public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        
            char[] chtest = {'1', '*', '0', '*'};
            generateComb(chtest, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening here is that when you say `ch[index] = '0';` you're *changing that object*, and you're not setting that character *back* to a `*`, therefore after the second `*` gets turned to a `1`, it's no longer replaced. This is called *pass by reference*, `char[] ch` is a reference to the string. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) for an example.

This should work:

```html
public class TestClass{
        public static void generateComb (char[] ch, int index) {
            if (index == ch.length)
            {
                System.out.println (ch);

                return;
            }
            if (ch[index]=='*'){

                ch[index] = '0';
                generateComb (ch, index+1);
                ch[index] = '1';
                generateComb (ch, index+1);
                ch[index] = '*'; // <-------------- here
            }
            else {
                generateComb (ch, index+1);   
                
            }
        }
        
        public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        
            char[] chtest = {'1', '*', '0', '*'};
            generateComb(chtest, 0);
        }
    }
```

An example of what's going on in each round might help:

- ch = [1, *, 0, *], index == 0
- ch = [1, *, 0, *], index == 1 *ch[1] changed to '0'*
- ch = [1, 0, 0, *], index == 2
- ch = [1, 0, 0, *], index == 3 *ch[3] changed to '0'*
- ch = [1, 0, 0, 0], index == 4 **prints: 1000** *returns to prior call and ch[3] is changed to '1'*
- ch = [1, 0, 0, 1], index == 4 **prints: 1001** *returns up the call stack, ch[1] is changed to '1'*
- ch = [1, 1, 0, 1], index == 2
- ch = [1, 1, 0, 1], index == 3
- ch = [1, 1, 0, 1], index == 4 **prints: 1101**

Using a debugger to step through this might help further show the problem

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly the gap what I'm missing.